# MariaDB: Show TOP 5 results per member (in pivot table)

Tags: mariadb, pivot-table

I have a table in my MariaDB database that looks like this (simplified example);

| Date | Member | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-3-2023 | Paul | 10 |
| 2-3-2023 | Paul | 6 |
| 3-3-2023 | Paul | 9 |
| 4-3-2023 | Paul | 9 |
| 5-3-2023 | Paul | 6 |
| 6-3-2023 | Paul | 5 |
| 7-3-2023 | Paul | 3 |
| 2-3-2023 | Sarah | 8 |
| 3-3-2023 | Sarah | 9 |

and so on.

What I'd like to do is show the TOP 5 Grades per member (preferably sorted by date) in a pivot table. If there is less than 5 results I'd like the rest to be either displayed as 0 or NULL (either one is fine). Each combination of grade+date should be treated as a seperate result. In the above table the top 5 grades of Paul should be 10,9,9,6,6

So to illustrate, the desired result would be;

| Member | Grade 1 | Grade 2 | Grade 3 | Grade 4 | Grade 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 10 | 6 | 9 | 9 | 6 |
| Sarah | 8 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I know how to create a pivot table but the ones I created before were grouped by a certain other field (like month). I'm not quite sure how to do this with the Top 5 results. Certainly not when having them in the order of the date the grade was achieved.

Comment: if you're using a version with window functions, you can use `RANK()` and then use that as the pivot column.

Comment: @Barmar Your suggestion really helped me out, to be honest I didn't quite know about the 'RANK' function but when I figured out how it works it was pretty easy getting my desired output from there. If you can submit your comment as an answer I can mark yours as the one that solved my question.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after suggestion by Barmar.

For anyone struggling with this question, I got my desired result by using this query;

```
SELECT Member,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 1 THEN Grade END) as '1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 2 THEN Grade END) as '2',
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 3 THEN Grade END) as '3',
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 4 THEN Grade END) as '4',
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rank = 5 THEN Grade END) as '5',
      FROM (SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY member ORDER BY Grade DESC) Rank, Member, Grade FROM table) pivot
GROUP BY Member
```

Answer (score -1):

What I do is

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Grade DESC;
```

This sort the table in descending order then store in a variable.
then I iterate through while also creating a counter variable

```
i=1;
while(r.next()&&i<=5)
{
   .....
   i++;
}
```